# Should I award a bounty early if there is a satisfactory answer?

Tags: discussion, bounty, best-practices

Recently I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2753743/let-f-in-mathbbzx-is-the-number-of-roots-of-barf-in-bar-mathbb). It originally received very little attention (and only one cryptic-to-me answer in a comment), so I placed a bounty on it. It now has an answer which I like; hence I upvoted it and (eventually) accepted it as an answer.

> Should I now also award the bounty early?

To some extent, it seems like paying for the bounty is paying for it to be on the featured questions list for a week. Hence, if I award the bounty early, then (I assume) it will no longer be in the featured questions list. Of course, what I really wanted was a satisfactory answer, and that is what I got. Hence, I'm thinking I may as well award the bounty now. (I did at least wait a while for the answer to be upvoted by others to see of the community also liked the answer.)

One thing I'm concerned with is the following:

> Do people find it annoying that a question with an accepted answer stays on the featured question list?

Perhaps, readers think, "Why is this question taking up space on the featured questions list? It already has a good, upvoted, accepted answer."

Comment: IMHO, just wait one or two more days. I have observed an interesting pattern. Either a bounty question doesn't receive any answers in early few days of the bounty period or if someone post an answer, multiple answers will arrive in a short period of time. It seems for bounty question, people will compose their answers more carefully before posting. If you didn't receive another answer within one or two days after the first answer, it is a reasonable bet no one else is having a good answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that I have found when it comes both to bounties that I've given and received is this:

> Questions that are under an active bounty receive increased attention - particularly, when the bounty is close to expiration. As a result, both the question and good answers to those questions receive up votes.

Thus, I recommend that you wait until the bounty expires and award the bounty during the grace period. If you receive an even better answer, then great. If you don't, then the answer that you like will rewarded even more.